# Query with concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Input Table:** Occupations

```
Name      Occupation
_____     _________
Samantha    Doctor
Julia       Actor
Maria       Actor
Meera       Singer
Ashley    Professor
Ketty     Professor
Christen    Professor
Jane        Actor
Jenny       Doctor
Priya       Singer
```

**Output:**

```
 Detail
__________  
Samantha(D) 
Julia(A)
Maria(A)
Meera(S)
Ashley(P)
```

That means output will contain name concatenated with First alphabet of each occupations.

```
Select concat(Name,'()') from Occupations
```

This query gives the concatenated brackets ,but I have to add alphabet based on one's profession.What should I do to accomplish that?

Comment: How come there are 10 persons in the table, but only 5 in the output?

Comment: Oh! I just omit the others...

Comment: Can't you simply adjust the sample table data, have those 5 extra rows removed?

Answer (score 3):

**For SQL 2012:**
    select 
    concat
    (name,'(',substring(occupation,1,1),')')
    from
    table

**For other versions..**
select 
name +'('+ substring(occupation,1,1)+')' 
    from
    table

Concat ignores null values,but you may want to be carefull with '+' since whole output will become null in case any of the expression is null,you can use Isnull to avoid that